# Need Help passing field data from one content type to another

Tags: views

I am working on an Equipment Checkout system using Drupal 7, MERCI, views, panels, rules, and many other modules. I am working for a community college in Oregon. I am upgrading features on an already running system that was built by myself with the help of a few other people last year. The system is offline for the summer.

Before I jump into the nuts and bolts of the question let me give you a little information on our workflow.

When the Student want to checkout equipment (cameras, microphones, whatever) we first open up the students customer account. This is a content type called customer, that has various fields containing data about the student, name, email, L# etc. We do this to verify the identity of the student as well as to make sure that they can actually check out the equipment they are requesting.

After we have verified the students credentials. We then create a new reservation, that is also a content type. Then we input the student information into the reservation.

So what I want to do: Have a button or link on the customer page that will capture the customer data, create a reservation, and then put the data in the appropriate place.

I have done some searching looking for answers and this seems to be a common problem, but the specifics always seem to throw me off. I've tried a few modules to attempt this, autofill and prepopulate but with no success.

This is the first of many features that I am trying to implement over the next 3 months, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. I would approach this with an entity reference field, a block, and rules.

Your reservation content type should have an entity reference field for the 'customer' record.

A block would have the button to click. It goes on your customer record page. You might need a module like [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link)  to trigger rules.

Set up rules so that when you click this button it:

- creates a new entity (a node of type reservation)
- populates the user reference field with the customer node you are looking at
- saves the new node
- opens the edit screen on the new node so more work can be done

It will take some playing around play around with rules to get it right.

Comment: I think your work flow is solid. I did some looking into rules_link and it looks like a good solution, now I just need to figure out Rules. lol Time to do some research on rules now. Thanks :)

Comment: Any chance you know rules well enough to help me get them in place. I can create the new reservation, but after that I get lost.  Thanks :)